# VS2012 Team Systems Source Control cannot resolve conflicts due to pending changes

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2012

I have a case where I have a single conflict in a multiple project solution. I would like to use the "Keep Local Version" option but this fails due to "pending changes".  There is no "Merge Changes Manually" option.  I cannot delete the file from Source Control Explorer because of "pending changes".  I am the sole developer on this project.  Is there any way to override conflicts warnings on a single file and force a check in?

Comment: Copy the file, undo changes, redo changes?

Comment: Hi BNL - I did make a backup of the file followed by an Undo Pending Changes and attempted check in - this gave the same message - cannot check in - file already has pending changes. Renaming the file or deleting the file gives the same error.

I will check with our admin and see if there is a way he can clear pending changes on a single file.